# Retrieve user data from Firebase database and display in user profile textfields

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I want to retrieve user data from the Firebase database (data such as: username, email, age, gender, height) and display it in text fields that are located in my UserProfileViewController. I have successfully been able to store the user data inside my database when the user signs up and creates a profile. However, I am having trouble getting that data back from the database and displaying it inside the users profile view controller. How would I be able to display the user age in the ageTextField, user gender in the genderTextField, etc.?

I have tried to create a dictionary for the values (username, email, age, gender, height, etc.) in the CreateProfileViewController, but it did not seem to work when I tried to retrieve them in the UserProfileViewController. I was wondering if someone could help me with this problem?

This is part of my CreateProfileViewController, which stores the users data into the database:

```
//reference database
var ref : DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

 func profile(){

//get data from the current user who signed up (their uid and email), so that the profile data can be stored under the same user) 

        let key = ref.childByAutoId().key 
        let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email 


let user = [
                    "id": key,
                    "email": email,
                    "age": ageTextField.text! as String,
                    "gender": genderTextField.text! as String,
            "weight": weightTextField.text! as String,
            "height": heightTextField.text! as String,
            "monthlyGoal": monthlyGoalTextField.text! as String
        ]

self.ref.child(key).setValue(user)

}

 @IBAction func submitProfile(_ sender: Any) {
        profile()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSegue", sender: self)
        print("User profile created!")//this takes them to the home page view controller once they successfully sign up and create a profile.

    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code aswell.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share some code of how you tried to retrieve User's data from the Firebase database. Otherwise it would be hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: Show how do you store the user data inside the database when the user signs up and creates a profile

Comment: @RajeshKumarR, this is what I used to store the user data inside Firebase database, I hope this helps.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR, oh okay thank you, I just fixed that part of my code. Do you know how I can successfully retrieve the user data from the database?

Comment: @Amina404 I've updated my answer. Check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uid` as key for storing user details. Use `let key = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` instead of `let key = ref.childByAutoId().key`

```
func profile() {
    guard let key = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email 
    let user = ["id": key,
                "email": email,
                "age": ageTextField.text! as String,
                "gender": genderTextField.text! as String,
                "weight": weightTextField.text! as String,
                "height": heightTextField.text! as String,
                "monthlyGoal": monthlyGoalTextField.text! as String]
    self.ref.child(key).setValue(user)
}
```

Retrieve user details from the Firebase using the `currentUser?.uid`

```
func getUserDetails() {
    guard let key = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    self.ref.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        self.emailTextField.text = value?["email"] as? String
        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```